# Using the nth package for Roman Numerals

Tags: document-classes, roman-numerals

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{nth}
\begin{document}
\nth{3} is not the same as $\nth{3}$
\end{document}
```

This code works fine for numbers.Now , In the argument if I want to pass III , what should I do?

I want the output as III(in slanting--> I achieved this using Math Mode)rd(in super script)

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I'm having trouble understanding the problem. As I understand it, you want a text command which will produce the equivalent of `$\nth{3}$`. Is that right? Where does superscript come in? On second thoughts, where do roman numerals come in? Why would you want e.g. 'IIIrd', if that is what you want?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think it's standard practice in English to write something like `ii^{nd}`, `iii^{rd}`, `iv^{th}`, etc.  While I believe I may have seen this sort of thing in other languages, I cannot ever recall seeing it in English.  For example, we write King Henry VII, and though we say King Henry the seventh, we don't write `VII^{th}`.

Comment: There is `\textsuperscript{...}` available outside of a math environment.

Comment: By the way, your code doesn't give me superscript at all right now. Is that expected?

Comment: Writing `III^{rd}` is simply wrong. Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks @A.Ellett,I didn't know that , Won't do that again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then (as has been suggested in comments to the question) I think it is not a standard practice in English to write something like `III^{rd}`, let alone using italicized font, and I would suggest you not to use this.

That being said, one way to achieve what you want is to define a command similar to `\nth`, but converting the argument to (upper case) Roman numerals. Three options: one, using roman font for the complete expression; another one using slanted font for the numeral and roman font for the superscript, and the third one, using slanted font for the complete expression:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\def\Rnth#1{{% First print number:
  \expandafter\nthM \MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\number#1}\relax
  \nthscript{%
  \ifnum#1\nthtest0 th\else % negatives are all ``th'' (depending on \nthtest)
  \expandafter \nthSuff \expandafter 0\number\ifnum #1<0-\fi#1\delimiter
  \fi
 }}}
\def\RSnth#1{{% First print number:
  \expandafter\nthM \slshape\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\number#1}\kern1pt\relax
  \nthscript{%
  \ifnum#1\nthtest0 th\else % negatives are all ``th'' (depending on \nthtest)
  \expandafter \nthSuff \expandafter 0\number\ifnum #1<0-\fi#1\delimiter
  \fi
 }}}
\def\Rsnth#1{{% First print number:
  \expandafter\nthM \slshape\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\number#1}\kern-1pt\relax}
  \nthscript{%
  \ifnum#1\nthtest0 th\else % negatives are all ``th'' (depending on \nthtest)
  \expandafter \nthSuff \expandafter 0\number\ifnum #1<0-\fi#1\delimiter
  \fi
 }}

\begin{document}

\Rnth{3} is not the same as \nth{3}.

\Rnth{2} is not the same as \nth{2}.

\RSnth{3} is not the same as \nth{3}.

\RSnth{2} is not the same as \nth{2}.

\Rsnth{3} is not the same as \nth{3}.

\Rsnth{2} is not the same as \nth{2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the numeral to be in italics shape, replace `\slshape` with `\itshape` in the corresponding definition(s).

In my opinion, the two options using slanted font look really ugly; please consider not using those.